# NPP: Overlapping computation and data transfer

Tags: cuda, npp

CUDA allows to overlap computation and data transfer using *cuMemcpy* async functions and *streams*. But is it possible with NPP(Performance Primitives)?

A little background. I am trying to utilize GPU using NPP image resize functions (in our case it is *nppiResize_8u_C3R*). I am using pinned memory and successfully transfer data to GPU using *cuMemcpy2DAsync_v2* and *per thread stream*. The problem is that *nppiResize_8u_C3R* and all other computation functions do not accept streams.

When I run Nvidia Visual Profiler I see the next:

1. Pinned memory allows me to transfer data faster - ~6.524 GB/s.
2. The percentage of time when memcpy is being performed in parallel with compute is 0%.

Answer (score 2):

> The problems [sic] is that nppiResize_8u_C3R and all other computation functions do not accept streams.

NPP is fundamentally a stateless API. However, to use streams with NPP, you use `nppSetStream` to set the default stream for subsequent operations. There are several caveats noted on page 2 of the documentation about using NPP with streams and recommended synchronization practices when switching streams.

Comment: Is it possible to get a performance boost using *nppSetStream*? I tried it, but had no success. I have a feeling that NPP is not designed for concurrent or overlap scenarios, and to utilize GPU I need to use CUDA driver API directly.